# Delay/Time Objective-C Statement Execution

Tags: objective-c

So I have this code moving an NSButton to the coordinates listed

```
[[MyNSButton animator] setFrame:NSMakeRect(567, 228, 109, 151)];
```

Then I have the same code moving another NSButton

```
[[MyNSButton2 animator] setFrame:NSMakeRect(695, 228, 109, 151)];
```

What I want to do is have the first statement execute, and then when the entire animation is over, and after a delay of maybe .5 seconds, have the next one go. How can I do that?

Comment: Just a tip: unless `MyNSButton` and `MyNSButton2` are classes, they should be written in camelCase instead of PascalCase.

Comment: You're right, I normally do that, I just did that when I changed them for this question.

Comment: (>.>) sure you did :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `NSTimer`
Here is the code how to do that

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(getnextButton) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

where `getnextButton` is the method that would be called after .5 seconds.
put the code in this method which you want to execute after .5 seconds.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: This will cause timing issues since NSTimer is not precise and can be "held up" if the computer is busy.

Comment: NSTimer is a fine approach for the purpose of animations. Mac OS X is hardly a real-time operating system. Also, instead of voting down and criticizing an answer, suggest a better one.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. However, is it possible to have the delay without splitting the actions into two different methods? Like basically just have the computer not execute any code for the .5 seconds.

Comment: @kperryua Voting on answers and criticizing those you feel need it is exactly what this site is for. As for suggesting better ones, did you happen to notice my answer where I steered the OP to the OS's animation API? It's far more efficient at this than using a bunch of NSTimers.

Comment: @Joshua I didn't notice your answer at the time I replied to your comment. My apologies. Unfortunately, the reference you pointed to is not relevant to `-animator` driven animations, only NSAnimations. (FWIW, both NSAnimation and non-layer-backed `-animator` proxy animations are driven by NSTimer and perform acceptably well, refuting your argument that NSTimers are "inefficient" for animations.)

Comment: Yes NSTimer is good approach,I have done that.Moreover animations can be used for that Like CABasicAnimation.Well no problem kperryua,but finally you realized that.Thanks.

Comment: Your answer helped me voted up. I wish I could vote up twice :)

Answer (score 11):

Or you can do this as well but again you need to take method for that.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(onGeocoding:) withObject:nil afterDelay:60.0];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want to delay code execution then you can let the main thread sleep using this:

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0];
```

This will delay the thread for 5 seconds and then the execution would start.Put this statement where you want the delay. Hope this would help you.

Comment: Please. Only put actual code in code environments. Review the Markdown syntax: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax.

Comment: This will block the main thread and effectively freeze the UI until the timer completes. It would also not have any effect on the animations, which are running asynchronously. This is not how animation is done on OS X or iOS. The ONLY way to perform multiple keyframe animations in the most efficient way the OS can muster is by using the animation API.

Comment: That is not for animation that is just to halt your application for the time period..I better understand.

Comment: This helped me for a different purpose, so I edited it as per @JonathanSterling.

Comment: i think your code above sleeps the thread for .5 (1/2) second, not 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into the Animation Programming Guide for Cocoa, specifically the [Setting and Handling Progress Marks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AnimationGuide/Articles/TimingAnimations.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003581-DontLinkElementID_3) section. When the animation finishes moving to the second rect, trigger moving back to the first; when it's back to the first, trigger moving to the second, ad infinitum.

Answer (score 1):

I thing this kind of codes will be helpful. make a new queue (thread) and make it sleep! Thats it...

> dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("loadqueue", nil), ^{
>           [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
>           //codes here...
>       });